# incomplete downloading error while installing a package in R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-package

i am trying to install lubridate package in r using following syntax 
    install.packages("lubridate")

but it is throwing a error by saying that it is not able to download package       completely
below is the error where you can see that downloaded size is not equal to reported size

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/vikas.mittal/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)  
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/lubridate_1.6.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 654286 bytes (638 KB)
downloaded 248 KB

Warning in install.packages :
downloaded length 253952 != reported length 654286   
Warning in install.packages :
error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open compressed file 'lubridate/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such  file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

Comment: You can change the CRAN server or download it direct from http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/lubridate_1.6.0.zip and install it as zip in RStudio.

Comment: i downloaded this file into in local also and then tried to install this package but still getting following error                                                    unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\vikas.mittal\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\file22f84cfd4b05\lubridate’ to ‘C:\Users\vikas.mittal\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\lubridate’

Comment: Check in `.../R/win-library/3.3/` for `lubridate` (remove or move out of the way if present) and/or any directories starting with `0` (temporary dirs during installation process).

Comment: Can help me with this related post please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200536/r-unable-to-install-r-packages-cannot-open-the-connection